Orientable (?) optimal edge-coloring for a directed acyclic graph
The problem
Let's say there are P processes to be executed one at a time with no interruptions, some of them depending on some others' outputs.
According to a predetermined dependency scheme, each process reads from at most R input files and writes to 0 or 1 output files, but cannot rewrite its inputs on the fly; processes that don't have to read always start first, processes that have all their dependencies satisfied can run in an arbitrary order. Files can be read multiple times and rewritten when no longer needed.
There's a guarantee of no cyclic dependencies, so I believe the processes may be interpreted as vertices of a DAG, with files being arcs.
The question
For a given dependency scheme, how do I find the execution order with the smallest (and if not the smallest then at least reasonably small) number of reusable files that can satisfy the dependencies for all P processes?
My thoughts
AFAICT under these conditions the total number of files cannot be smaller than the max input degree of the graph, plus 1.
The problem is that it's not always possible to reach that total — e.g. if there are 9 processes connected as one K3,3 on top of the other K3,3 with all arcs directed downwards (multiple outgoing arcs being a single output file that's read multiple times) then there's nothing that can be done to squeeze the total into 3+1=4.
Unfortunately, in my case it's prohibitively expensive to bruteforce that number by comparing the buffer counts for all possible topologically sorted execution orders, since the typical P's often exceed 10000.
Something tells me that this has much to do with the edge-coloring problem, but the outputs that have to be the same color confuse me a great deal — even though I'm pretty certain that there exists a well-known algorithm just for this.
Please help me find it.

This sounds NP-hard to me, but I can't easily show it. That said, I wouldn't think of this as a coloring problem. It's really, "how can I minimize the maximum number of open dependencies". I would suggest that you write an algorithm to try to optimize an existing solution. Then find multiple random solutions, optimize each, and pick the best one.

This sounds close to the register allocation problem which is typically approached with vertex colouring.
